# Solve overdetermined set using Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

As shown below, this is a overdetermined system. Could you teach me how to find the optimized solution in Mathematica? I know it could be solved by the method of least square, but how to realize it in Mathematica?

```
{E0 - 2 x + 2 y + 2 a - 2 c == 0.,
 E0 - 2 x + 2 y - 2 a + 2 c == 0.2, 
 E0 - 2 x - 2 y - 2 a - 4 b - 2 c == 0.032, 
 E0 + 2 x + 2 y - 2 a - 4 b - 2 c == 0.143, 
 E0 + 2 x - 2 y - 2 a + 2 c == 0.436, 
 E0 + 2 x - 2 y + 2 a - 2 c == 0.222, 
 E0 - 2 x - 2 y + 2 a + 4 b + 2 c == 0.275, 
 E0 + 2 x + 2 y + 2 a + 4 b + 2 c == 0.416}
```

Comment: Look up `LeastSquares[]`. Make sure you know how to formulate this in matrix-vector format.

Comment: Hi, @J.M. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: alternatively `NMinimize[Plus @@ (sys /. Equal[a_, b_] -> (a - b)^2),
 {E0, x, y, a, b, c}]`

Comment: @chris Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As @Guess who it is. states in the comments, an overdetermined linear problem can be solved using *Mathematica's* `LeastSquares[]` functionality.

To input your above system of equations:

```
a = {{1, -2, 2, 2, 0, -2}, {1, -2, 2, -2, 0, 2}, 
    {1, -2, -2, -2, -4, -2}, {1, 2, 2, -2, -4, -2}, 
    {1, 2, -2, -2, 0, 2}, {1, 2, -2, 2, 0, -2}, 
    {1, -2, -2, 2, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2}};

b = {0, .2, 0.032, 0.142, 0.436, 0.222, 0.275, 0.416};
```

Now to solve:

```
sol = LeastSquares[a, b]
```

> `{0.215375, 0.0443125, -0.0129375, -0.0151042, 0.0215417, 0.0366458}`

And to check how good the fit is:

```
ListPlot[Thread[{b, a.sol}], AxesLabel -> {"Actual", "Predicted"}, Epilog -> Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]
```

[image]

Looks good. To explore further, we can use `LinearModelFit[]` to give us more detail about our model.

```
lm = LinearModelFit[{a, b}];

lm[{"FitResiduals", "RSquared"}]
```

> `{{0.002625, -0.004375, 0.008625, -0.006875, 
>     0.002625, -0.004375, -0.006875, 0.008625}, 0.998342}`

Also, you can use `CoefficientArrays[]` to build your coefficient matrix and vector.

```
{b0, a0} = Normal@CoefficientArrays[{e0 - 2 x + 2 y + 2 a - 2 c == 0, etc...}, {e0, x, y, a, b, c}]
```

And then:

```
LeastSquares[a0, -b0]
```

Comment: …and of course, one can use `CoefficientArrays[]` to form the matrix and vector from the equations. Still, for problems like these, it's best to skip the equations altogether and just input the matrix directly.

Comment: @J.M. Exactly. This one took exactly 20 seconds of keying to get the coefficient matrix input. Probably should put something in the answer about `CoefficientArrays[]` though...

Comment: Dear @kale  and J.M.  Thanks for your helpful tutorial and discussion for this kind of overdetermined system. With your help, I have reproduced the results which are in good agreement with others' reports. Great thanks again.